# GSM validation with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate a string for NON gsm characters. I have this code that works "almost" ok for my needs.

```
$gsm = '/[^-@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå_ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ \n\^{}\[~\]\|\$€ÆæßÉ!\"#¤%&\'\(\)\*\+,-\.\/0123456789:;<=>\?¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà]/';

    if(preg_match($gsm, $msg)){
        echo "fail!";
    }else{
        echo "passes";
    }
```

One of my tests is this string ->   **άββgΚ123 5ΑF**

This string contains the Greek letters "ά","β" (in lowercase) and I should see that fail.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My regEx was missing the /u modifier so it can handle unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution:

```
/^[...all the characters allowed...]*$/
```

This matches the *whole* string from start to end to ensure that the string is only comprised of the allowed characters.

Comment: Ι tested your suggestion, and nothing changed. I get the same "faulty" result.

Comment: Try putting your examples in regex.com and then share your result here

Comment: Tested both regex ( mine and yours) and works ok with any test. But when I use the if() of php its wrong. Thats really strange.

Comment: Check this http://laravel.io/bin/JlGwE and then this http://www.regexr.com/38tco .